# Activate a script on paint/drawing action

Tags: python, scripting

Here is a very simple rudimentary script that randomizes the color of the texture paint brush, however the script only randomizes when I run the scrip. Is it possible to instead have it randomize every time some paint placed, besides pairing the randomizing to the left click of my mouse??

```
import bpy
import random

brush = bpy.context.tool_settings.image_paint.brush

color= (random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1))
brush.color = color
```